# Boost::Spirit how to handle floating point exception

Tags: c++, parsing, exception, boost, boost-spirit

I am working with `boost::spirit` and i am parsing an arithmetic expression and expecting an integer result from the expression.
Also I want to handle any floating point exception that can occur while computing the result (say the input string expression has divide by 0 kind of scenario).
I need some help for catching such exceptions.

Below is a sample code snippet :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>


namespace math_calculator {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Our calculator grammar
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct calculator : qi::grammar<Iterator, int(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        calculator() : calculator::base_type(expression)
        {
            using qi::_val;
            using qi::_1;
            using qi::uint_;

            expression =
                term                            [_val = _1]
                >> *(   ('+' >> term            [_val += _1])
                    |   ('-' >> term            [_val -= _1])
                    )
                ;

            term =
                factor                          [_val = _1]
                >> *(   ('*' >> factor          [_val *= _1])
                    |   ('/' >> factor          [_val /= _1])
                    )
                ;

            factor =
                uint_                          [_val = _1]
                |   '(' >> expression           [_val = _1] >> ')'
                |   ('-' >> factor              [_val = -_1])
                |   ('+' >> factor              [_val = _1])
                ;
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, int(), ascii::space_type> expression, term, factor;
    };
}


typedef math_calculator::calculator<std::string::const_iterator> calculator;



int main()
{
    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

    calculator calc;
    std::string expression = "3/0";
    int result = 0;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = expression.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = expression.end();
                
    std::stringstream resultstream;
    try{
        bool r = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, boost::spirit::ascii::space, result);
        if (! (r && iter == end)) {
            result = 0;
        }
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Caught an exception." << std::endl;
    }
    
    resultstream.clear();
    resultstream << result;

    std::cout << "end: " << resultstream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

The code works fine if I change `int` to `double` returning `inf` as result.

Comment: Why change to double if you are expecting integers? When you do, why is `±INF` not a good enough  indication?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sehe. Actually, I am expecting integers only. Sorry, if the last sentence created any confusion. Could you please help in catching the exception part?